# Scraping <h2> inside a <div>

Tags: php, html, xpath, scrape

Just having some trouble scraping the `h2` on this code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
        <article class="article">
        <figure>
            <a title="Ölüm Denizi" href="http://trfilmizle.com/olum-denizi.html">
                <img class="small-poster" alt="Ölüm Denizi" src="http://i706.photobucket.com/albums/ww64/ddizi/TRfilmizle/OumlluumlmDenizi_zpsc809f300.jpg~original">
            </a>
        </figure>
    <div class="article-container">
    <h2>
        <a title="Ölüm Denizi" href="http://trfilmizle.com/olum-denizi.html">Ölüm Denizi</a>
    </h2>
    <div class="article-info">
    <div class="description"> Kuzey Kore, Güney Kore ve Çin arasına sıkışmış Yanji kentinde geçen Ölüm Denizi, araba kovalamacaları, cinayetler ve bıçaklı kavgalarla dolu… </div>
</div>
```

Any idea? I can access the nodes via:

```
//article[@class='article']/text()
```

But, can't get the `h2`! Any suggestions?

Comment: so you want text Ölüm Denizi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get all of the text components underneath `h2` elements in the `div`s:

```
//div/h2//*/text()
```

More specifically, you can limit it to specific `div`s:

```
//div[@class='article-container']/h2//*/text()
```

Comment: Hmm that doesnt seem to return anything when I run it in Firefox's Firebug (Xpath) console

Comment: @user3658366 I had to clean up the XML, but it works for me: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/c90b33f14208192d56a3432755243ed4

Comment: Thanks, yes I got that working just now too, it doesnt seem to work in PHP using DOMDocument though hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Use this [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<?php
$source= '<div id="content">
    <div class="title-wrapper">
        <article class="article">
        <figure>
            <a title="Ölüm Denizi" href="http://trfilmizle.com/olum-denizi.html">
                <img class="small-poster" alt="Ölüm Denizi" src="http://i706.photobucket.com/albums/ww64/ddizi/TRfilmizle/OumlluumlmDenizi_zpsc809f300.jpg~original">
            </a>
        </figure>
    <div class="article-container">
    <h2>
        <a title="Ölüm Denizi" href="http://trfilmizle.com/olum-denizi.html">Ölüm Denizi</a>
    </h2>
    <div class="article-info">
    <div class="description"> Kuzey Kore, Güney Kore ve Çin arasına sıkışmış Yanji kentinde geçen Ölüm Denizi, araba kovalamacaları, cinayetler ve bıçaklı kavgalarla dolu… </div>
</div>';
preg_match_all('#<h2>(.*?)</h2>#is', $source, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($output[1][0]);
exit;
```